# Complete Intersection and twist

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to tackle exercise 5.3.3 of Liu's Book, and i have trouble with proving the following fact.
If $X=V_+(f_1,...,f_d)$ is of dimension n-d in $\mathbb P^n_k$ then if we call $Z=V_+(f_1,...,f_{d-1})$, and $I$ the ideal defining $X$ in $\mathcal O_Z $, then $I$ is isomorphic to $O_Z(-\deg f_d)$. Could anyone enlighten me?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

We can write $$X=V_+(f_1,\dots,f_d)=H_1\cap\dots\cap H_d=Z\cap H_d,$$ 
where $H_j=V_+(f_j)\subset \mathbb P^n$ has ideal sheaf $\mathscr I_{H_j}=(f_j)^\sim\subset \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}$. The ideal sheaf of $X$ is

$$\mathscr I_X=\mathscr I_{H_1}+\dots +\mathscr I_{H_d}=(f_1,\dots,f_d)^\sim\subset\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\rightsquigarrow\,\,\,\,\,\mathscr O_X=\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}/\mathscr I_X,$$

that of $Z$ is

$$\mathscr I_Z=\mathscr I_{H_1}+\dots +\mathscr I_{H_{d-1}}=(f_1,\dots,f_{d-1})^\sim\subset\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}\,\,\,\,\,\rightsquigarrow\,\,\,\,\,\mathscr O_Z=\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}/\mathscr I_Z.$$

Let $S$ be the graded ring $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$, so that $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}=S^\sim$. There is an exact sequence
$$0\to S(-\deg f_d)\to S/(f_1,\dots,f_{d-1})\to S/(f_1,\dots,f_d)\to 0.$$

By applying the (exact) functor $(-)^\sim$, we get
$$0\to I\to \mathscr O_Z\to \mathscr O_X\to 0,$$ the ideal short exact sequence of $X=Z\cap H_d$ inside $Z$.

Comment: This puzzles me because this seems completely general and doesnt use the fact that $Z$ and $X$ are complete intersections in $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: We do use it to describe the ideal sheaves of $X,Z\subset \mathbb P^n$.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still dont' see it, what if we were to take $V_+(x,xy)$ in $P^3$.
The exact sequence whould be $0\to 0 \to k[y,z]\to k[y,z]\to 0$ and this ideal sheaf defining $X$ in $Z$ would not be $O(-2)$ but zero. I feel i need to use the hauptidealsatz somewhere to justify that your exact sequence, over $P^n$, when restricted to $Z$, identifes $f_d O_{P^n}$ with $O_Z(-n)$... Sorry i'm really new at this.

Comment: Your example does not quite work, because $V_+(x)\subset V_+(xy)$ (in other words $Z=X$). I think it is ideal to understand the situation for hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$: if it is clear that the ideal sheaf of such a $Y\subset \mathbb P^n$ is $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}(-\deg Y)$, then the condition "complete intersection" is exactly what you need in order to extend this to the situation $X\subset Z\subset\mathbb P^n$.